# Selecting only specified columns from result set in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I wish to select only tp_info_false and tp_info_true columns from TestDescription table and I have tried the following:

using pluck:

```
td=TestDescription.where(test_point_id:test_point.id).pluck(:tp_info_true,:tp_info_false).first
```

using select:

```
td=TestDescription.where(test_point_id:test_point.id).select(:tp_info_true,:tp_info_false).first
```

value1 = td[0]
value2 = td [1]

Using the above two methods I get an error saying "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)". please correct my query.Thanks!

Comment: first check out a few links: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3 http://erniemiller.org/2010/03/28/advanced-activerecord-3-queries-with-arel/.. if somebody will solve the problem for you, you won´t learn it by yourself..

Comment: Is this the same way, You are assigning the values in your code..?

Comment: yeah ... using the returned values from td[0], td[1]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select`, like:

```
TestDescription.select([:tp_info_false, :tp_info_true])
```

this method accepts only one argument. If you want to select more than one column, you need to put their names in array, like I did.